# Вывод кастом макроса в UMI CMS

Tags: php, xslt, шаблонизаторы, umi

Создал свою функцию в custom.php. пытаюсь вывести ее в шаблоне такой строчкой

```
<xsl:value-of select="document('udata://custom/gettimedata/')/udata" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

Если я прописываю это, например, в файле xslt/blocks/footer.xsl, то функция выводит все как надо. Но если прописать в xslt/layouts/default.xsl, там где мне нужно, то не выводит ничего. 
Как вывести результат функции в дефолтном шаблоне?

Comment: Очень странно. Место вызова не должно влиять. Попробуй включить показ ошибок (в config.ini в корне задать параметру debug значение 1). Возможно просто где-то выше вызова макроса есть какая-нибудь ошибка.

Comment: @ArthurShiriev Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Comment: @ArthurShiriev спасибо, помогло. В дебаг мод вылезла ошибка о том что функция выдает строку в кодировке отличной от utf-8, пофиксил и все заработало.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Место вызова макроса не должно влиять на его работу.

Рекомендую включить показ ошибок. Возможно возникает какая-либо ошибка при генерации страницы выше вызова макроса.

Для включения показа ошибок в файле config.ini, который находится в корне сайта, нужно в секции "debug" задать параметру "enabled" значение 1.